# Swift Regular Expressions name validate Vietnamese name

Tags: regex, swift

I use following to validate VietNamese address, it work on web https://regex101.com but wrong when I used on my swift project.

```
extension String {
func isValidAddress() -> Bool {
    let RegEx = "([0-9A-ZẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ']+\\s?\\b){2,}"
    let Test = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", RegEx)
    return Test.evaluate(with: self.uppercased())
}
```

}

My test string " 123/13 Hương lộ 2. Khu phố 2, Quận Bình Tân. Phường Bình Trị Đông A"

It correct when I delete "." "/" and "," like: 12313 Hương lộ 2 Khu phố 2 Quận Bình Tân. Phường Bình Trị Đông A

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are your requirements? Your regex does not match `.`, `/` and `,` - if you need to match them, add to the `[...]` Note that `MATCHES` requires a full string match, and your regex does not match the full string. So, what do you need?

Comment: If you want to make sure there are 2 or more whitespaces in the string and there may be letters/digits/punctuation inside, try `[\\w\\p{P}]+(?:\\s[\\w\\p{P}]+)+"`

Comment: Or  just add `.*` at the start and end of the pattern if you do not care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of al, `MATCHES` with `NSPredicate` requires a full string match. Since your pattern  does not match punctuation, it can't match the `" 123/13 Hương lộ 2. Khu phố 2, Quận Bình Tân. Phường Bình Trị Đông A"` string.

Depending on your requirements, either use a [`range(of:options:range:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642786-range) with your current pattern that allows partial match:

```
return self.range(of: "(?i)([0-9A-ZẮẰẲẴẶĂẤẦẨẪẬÂÁÀÃẢẠĐẾỀỂỄỆÊÉÈẺẼẸÍÌỈĨỊỐỒỔỖỘÔỚỜỞỠỢƠÓÒÕỎỌỨỪỬỮỰƯÚÙỦŨỤÝỲỶỸỴ']+\\s?\\b){2,}", options: .regularExpression) != nil
```

(Note that `(?i)` is a shorter way to tell the regex engine that the pattern is case insensitive). Or else, add those patterns to the regex that you expect to appear in the input string.

E.g. you may match your string fully with `"[\\w\\p{P}]+(?:\\s[\\w\\p{P}]+)+"` pattern where `\w` matches any letters, digits and `_`, `\p{P}` matches any punctuation (you might think of using just `\S` instead to match any non-whitespaces).

Comment: Well, you may even add `/`, `.` and `,` into the `[...]`, say, after `[`, so that they could be matched.

Comment: before post the question, i try to add ./, after[ but it didn't work, btw thanks for your help

Comment: i try with your " self.range(of:..." and it working, thank @Wiktor